# How do ethereum Dapps coins affect ethereum price?

Tags: ether, dapps, gas-price

I mean, if, for example price of Akasha coins will rise, shoult it affect price of ethereum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same as any fiat currency. Since many altcoins including Akasha is running on top the ethereum wallets.

Since mainly running on public ethereum blockchain each and every transfer needs ethers to do. So obviously ethereum demand get an increase. Like any other currency value will increase depend on the supply and demand.